# ajax GET Not working (Service Data not getting)

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, jquery-mobile, get

We have URL when we hit URL [URL](http://janasenanews.com/MyService.asmx/GetUserLoginVerification?Username=9440325333&Password=9440325333) in browser we got data.  We got Data like

```
[{"UserId":"c2fbd9fb-a423-4d33-9ea4-3aa58f7b52cf","UserType":"Parent","OutPutMessage":"Sucess"}].
```

But We need get data through ajax call.we tried like this

```
window.onload = function (){
 $.ajax({
url:'http://janasenanews.com/MyService.asmx/GetUserLoginVerification',
         data: {
             username:"9440325333",
             password :"9440325333"
         },
         type: "GET",
         dataType: 'JSON',
         success:function(data) {
            alert( data);
              //console.log("Here is the data", data);
         }
    });
    }
```

But We got two error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server

XMLHttpRequest cannot load  Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
```

Please guide to us what wrong in our code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Comment: It would be better if you copied the text of the error message into this question.

Answer (score 0):

Change your script with:

```
window.onload = function (){
$.ajax({
     url:'http://janasenanews.com/MyService.asmx/GetUserLoginVerification',
     data: {
         username:"9440325333",
         password :"9440325333"
     },
     type: "GET",
     dataType: 'JSON',
     success:function(data) {
        alert( data);
          //console.log("Here is the data", data);
     }
});
}
```

Comment: we tried as you said we got error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
ajaxcalling.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://janasenanews.com/MyService.asmx/GetUserLoginVerification?username=9440325333&password=9440325333. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Answer (score 0):

From the tags on your question it looks like you are making the ajax request from a Cordova app? If so, you will need to add the Cordova whitelist plugin to your app:

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-witelist`

And then in your `config.xml`, you'll need to add an `<access>` tag for your web service:

`<access origin="http://janasenanews.com" />`

or to allow all requests:

`<access origin="*" />`

On Android, you'll also need to add a Content Security Policy (CSP) to your `index.html`:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' janasenanews.com">`

More info on all of this is here: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist